# How do I use :base() and :this() correctly?

Tags: c#, constructor, this, grouping, radix

I've already searched about this issue both on SO and other websites but I haven't managed to find (or come to) a solution for my case.

I have an abstract class called `EnteBase`, which I use as a base (*duh!*) for other two classes, `Regione` and `Provincia`.

---

**`EnteBase`**:

```
public abstract class EnteBase
{
    public EnteBase ()
        : this( "Sconosciuto", 0 )
    {
    }

    public EnteBase ( string nome )
        : this( nome, 0 )
    {
    }

    public EnteBase ( string nome, int numeroComuni )
    {
        this.Nome = nome;
        this.NumeroComuni = numeroComuni;
    }


    private string nome;
    public string Nome
    {
        [...]
    }

    private int numeroComuni;
    public int NumeroComuni
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

---

**`Regione`**:

```
public class Regione : EnteBase
{
    public List<Provincia> Province
    {
        [...]
    }


    public Regione ()
        : base()
    {
        this.Province = new List<Provincia>();
    }

    public Regione ( string nome )
        : this()
    {
    }

    public Regione ( string nome, int numeroComuni )
        : this()
    {
    }


    public void AggiungiProvincia ( Provincia provincia )
    {
        Province.Add( provincia );
    }
}
```

---

**`Provincia`**:

```
public class Provincia : EnteBase
{
    private string sigla;

    public string Sigla
    {
        [...]
    }

    public Provincia ()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public Provincia ( string nome )
        : this()
    {
        this.Nome = nome;
    }

    public Provincia ( string nome, int numeroComuni )
        : this()
    {
        this.Nome = nome;
        this.NumeroComuni = numeroComuni;
    }

    public Provincia( string nome, int numeroComuni, string sigla)
        : this()
    {
        this.Nome = nome;
        this.NumeroComuni = numeroComuni;
        this.Sigla = sigla;
    }
}
```

---

My questions are the following:

- Is it correct to use `:this()` in all constructors of the base class except the one with most parameters, with the others pointing towards the latter?
- Is it correct to use `:this()` pointing to the base constructor in the classes `Provincia` and `Regione` and then assign to the fields from inside the method itself?

My problem rooted from the fact that I wanted to use both `:this()` and `:base()` in every method. When I discovered that it was not possible I looked for a solution, but I couldn't find a way to apply what I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797528/base-and-this-constructors-best-practices) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146152/c-if-a-class-has-two-constructors-what-is-the-best-way-for-these-constructors).

**P.S.:** in constructors, is it preferred to use `this.FieldName` or just `FieldName`?

Comment: I think you forgot to copy the field initialization into the `Regione` constructor.

Comment: @hvd Thank you, I accidentally left that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it correct to use :this() in all constructors of the base class
>   except the one with most parameters, with the others pointing towards
>   the latter?

The only use case is constructor chaining where you minimize your initialization work to one constructor and have all other constructor use `this()` with parameters that cause that constructor to execute - you are doing exactly this already in your `EnteBase` class.

An empty `base()`  call is generally useless, since the default base constructor is called by default anyway.

An empty `this()` call is going the wrong way and generally useless too (unless you have some initialization work that does not depend on the parameters) - you should pass parameters a constructor with more parameters is called, eventually ending up at the one constructor that does all the work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to use :this() pointing to the base constructor in the classes Provincia and Regione and then assign to the fields from inside the method itself?

In C#, a call to `:base()` is implicit, so it need not be done explicitly.

As a consequence of this, in your examples, you do not need the call to `:this()` since all this does is call the base parameterless constructor.

> Is it correct to use :this() in all constructors of the base class except the one with most parameters, with the others pointing towards the latter?

This is a common way of giving values sensible defaults, yes.

Comment: Is your first answer still valid for the class `Regione` now that I've used the parameterless constructor to initialize `this.Province`? If no, what should change?

Comment: @GabrieleCirulli You'll need to keep the call to `:this()`, or alternatively, initialise a backing field for the property inline.

Comment: is that the usual `private List<Provincia> province = new List<Provincia>()`?

Comment: @GabrieleCirulli Yep - you got it!

Answer (score 1):

You should change the following `Constructor` in the `subclass` from:

```
public Provincia ( string nome, int numeroComuni )
    : this()
{
    this.Nome = nome;
    this.NumeroComuni = numeroComuni;
}
```

**To:**

```
public Provincia ( string nome, int numeroComuni )
    : base(nome, numeroComuni)
{
}
```

**AND** the same in the following `Constructor`, from:

```
public Provincia( string nome, int numeroComuni, string sigla)
    : this()
{
    this.Nome = nome;
    this.NumeroComuni = numeroComuni;
    this.Sigla = sigla;
}
```

**To:**

```
public Provincia( string nome, int numeroComuni, string sigla)
    : base(nome, numeroComuni)
{
    this.Sigla = sigla;
}
```

Eliminating the need to set properties of the `superclass` in the `subclass`, as intended by the `superclass`es implementation.