# Constructor in Constructor

Tags: c#, java, constructor

is there some way how I can this do in C#? I can not use this(int,int) in C# code. Can you write me some similar code which will be in C# and will do the same things? Thank you! :)

```
public class JavaApplication2
{
    public static class SomeClass 
    {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public SomeClass () { this(90,90); }
        public SomeClass(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
        public void ShowMeValues ()
        {
            System.out.print(this.x);
            System.out.print(this.y);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SomeClass myclass = new SomeClass ();
        myclass.ShowMeValues();
    }
}
```

Comment: if both constructors are public why not using just second one with parameters? Or if you want some default value for `int x` and `int y` - just set it in Class definition as `private int x = 90; `

Comment: for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146152/c-if-a-class-has-two-constructors-what-is-the-best-way-for-these-constructors

Comment: possible duplicate of [call one constructor from another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009013/call-one-constructor-from-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that need to be changed if you want to translate this to C#:

1. The main the problem is that you've declared `SomeClass` as static. It won't compile because [static classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/79b3xss3.aspx) cannot have instance members. You need to remove the `static` keyword.
2. To invoke a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx) from another you need to use `: this(...)` after the constructor parameters (or `: base(...)` to invoke a constructor of the parent class).
3. Instead of `System.out`, for .NET applications you need to use [`System.Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx).

This should work for you:

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public SomeClass () : this(90,90) { }
    public SomeClass(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
    public void ShowMeValues ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.x);
        Console.WriteLine(this.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, C# can chain constructors:

```
public SomeClass() :this(90,90) {}
public SomeClass(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
```

This is covered on MSDN in [Using Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx).

That being said, in C#, the class will have to not be `static`, as well.