# Constructor Chaining Order

Tags: c#

If you chain constructor calls using the syntax:

```
public frmConfirm(): this(1)
```

when is the overloaded constructor called? Also, can somebody confirm that if the class is a form, problems will arise from having the InitializeComponent() call in both constructors?

Comment: @madmik3: it sure is simple to write code to see what happens. The question is then whether that is *guaranteed* to happen in all circumstances (different OS, different versions of the CLR).

Comment: A related post - [C# constructor execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1882692/465053).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The chained constructor will be called immediately prior to the body of the defining constructor.  The IL sequence generated is an immediate `call` to the other constructor, followed by the IL generated from the statements in the constructor.

So if you chain to another constructor and that constructor calls `InitializeComponent()` the calling constructor should not call this method.

For example, given this sample class:

```
class Foo {
    public int A, B;

    public Foo() : this(1) {
        B = 2;
    }

    public Foo(int a) {
        A = a;
    }
}
```

This is the generated IL:

```
  .class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Foo
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
  {
    .field  public  int32 A
    .field  public  int32 B

    // method line 1
    .method public hidebysig  specialname  rtspecialname
           instance default void '.ctor' ()  cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 8
        IL_0000:  ldarg.0
        IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
        IL_0002:  call instance void class Foo::'.ctor'(int32)
        IL_0007:  ldarg.0
        IL_0008:  ldc.i4.2
        IL_0009:  stfld int32 Foo::B
        IL_000e:  ret
    } // end of method Foo::.ctor

    // method line 2
    .method public hidebysig  specialname  rtspecialname
           instance default void '.ctor' (int32 a)  cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 8
        IL_0000:  ldarg.0
        IL_0001:  call instance void object::'.ctor'()
        IL_0006:  ldarg.0
        IL_0007:  ldarg.1
        IL_0008:  stfld int32 Foo::A
        IL_000d:  ret
    } // end of method Foo::.ctor

  } // end of class Foo
```

Note that the no-arg constructor calls the other constructor before assigning 2 to the B field.

Comment: won't the MSIL cause a circular reference? (i know it won't but i can't understand why) Seems like .ctor() is calling .ctor(int32 a) and vice versa. Can anyone clarify why this is not happening?

Comment: @arviman `Foo:.ctor()` is calling `Foo:.ctor(int32)`, but that in turn calls `System.Object:.ctor()`, ***not*** `Foo:.ctor()`.

Answer (score 15):

The `this(1)` constructor is called first.

As far as your second question goes, because of the `InitializeComponent` and other issues with form inheritance, I'd suggest you use composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 11):

The place to look for answers on a question like this is the [C# Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#constructor-initializers). In the section *Constructor initializers* you can read (emphasis is mine):

> All instance constructors (except
>   those for class object) implicitly
>   include an invocation of another
>   instance constructor **immediately
>   before** the constructor-body.

Further reading shows that:

- if the constructor has an instance constructor initializer of the form `base(arguments)`, a constructor from the direct base class will be invoked.
- if the constructor has an instance constructor initializer of the form `this(argument)`, a constructor in the class itself will be invoked.
- if no instance constructor initializer is provided, `base()` will be added automatically.