# Simple Constructor Chaining

Tags: c#

All, I have an application I want to lanch from another application or as a stand alone utility. To facilitate the start up of appA from appB, I use the following code in `Main()`/Program.cs

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new SqlEditorForm(args));
}
```

Now, in `SqlEditorForm` I have two constructors

```
public SqlEditorForm(string[] args)
    : this()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Test if called from appB...
    if (args != null && args.Count() > 0)
    {
        // Do stuff here...
    }
}
```

and the deafult

```
public SqlEditorForm()
{
    // Always do lots of stuff here...
}
```

This to me looks fine, but when run as stand alone (`args.Length = 0`) the `SqlEditorForm(string[] args)` constructor is getting called, and before it steps into the constructor to perform `InitializeComponent();`, it goes and initialises all of the global variables for the class *then* steps directly into the default constructor.

*Question, The chaining of the constructors seems to be happending in the wrong order. I want to know why?*

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What really is the question here?

Comment: The chaining of the constructors seems to be happending in the wrong order. I want to know why? Thanks.

Comment: Why down vote. It is a legitimate question - well formatted. spell checked with love. Not even so much as a comment to explain - well thats just bad manners...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609774/constructor-chaining-order

Comment: @Killercam I didn't downvote anything.

Comment: Not an issue. Sometimes it is difficult locate questions that have been asked before - I appreciate this may have duplication elsewhere, but I can find it. The above post talks about constructor chaining, which is _not_ complex. This is working differently to the way chaining of constructors _should_ work. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1785105/626442) seems to go some way to highlighting what is going on - but not all the way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all logic to constructor with parameter and call that constructor from parameterless one, passing default parameter value:

```
public SqlEditorForm()
    :this(null)
{        
}

public SqlEditorForm(string[] args)
{   
    InitializeComponent();
    // Always do lots of stuff here...

    if (args != null && args.Count() > 0)
    {
        // Do stuff here...
    }
}
```

Comment: But why should the parameterless constructor be called first; `: this()` says call the default _after_ the overridden constructor. It should not matter where I put `InitializeComponent();` should it!? The way I have set `Main(string[] args)` mean the overridden constructor should always be called...

Comment: @Killercam sorry, fixed (for some reason initially I thought about `base` call..) - move all logic to constructor with parameter. And call that constructor from your parameterless one, passing default parameter value.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is news to me! Clearly the ordering of the chaining for constructors in WinForms is somewhat different. Am I right in saying this? Again, thanks for your time...

Comment: @Killercam here is useful link about [Chanin Constructors refactoring](http://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/chainConstructors.html)

Comment: Thanks you. However, I want to note that this is not just about chaining. WinForms treats this chaining differently including the InitialisComponent() method...

Comment: @Killercam what do you mean by 'differently'? `Form` as an ordinal C# class, which behaves as other C# classes.

Comment: The way I had the constructors set up befor meant that the custom constructor for the form `SqlEditorForm(args[])` should have been called, _then_ `this()`, invoking the default constructor. The presence of `InitilizeComponent()` method changes this... See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1784683/626442)