# Call a method from constructor with "constructor rights"

Tags: c#, constructor, inline

I have a member. This member is only assigned by constructor, why I thought it could be made readonly. 
This very class has, several constructors.

Is there a way to assign this member once, to create a single point of failure.

First, I thought it could work with an inline method. 
The only way I found is with:

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
```

But it doesn't work.

Or is it possible to give a method "constructor rights" or is it impossible to do this?

Comment: That´s what `readonly` does.

Comment: use constructor chaining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your best bet here is to overload your constructors and then chain them

```
readonly int myReadonly;

public test(int a, int b) 
    :this (a)
{
    myReadonly = b;
}

private test(int a) 
{
    //other work
}
```

Comment: Stupid Question: Is that correct, when I call test(int a, int b) that this gets executed before (int a) gets called?

Comment: @KenanTabinas The question is **not stupid**. And it has been asked several times on SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4609774/982149).

Comment: @Fildor This is not the correct answer. I asked an "Is that true question". An answer to a such a question is a boolean. In this example, the correct answer where be "no". But thanks anyway.

Comment: @KenanTabinas Actually, it wasn't an answer to your question at all. I objected the statement of it being a stupid one and gave reference to a duplicate.