# How value of baseclass variable is deffering from derived class's variable?

Tags: c#

in c# program below value of baseclass deffers from derived class same variable which is inherited, baseclass is abstract, but variable is declared in baseclass only.
Here is the C# console program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApplication
{
    class MainClass
    {
        abstract class CBaseClass
        {
            public int iCount;

            public CBaseClass()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CBaseClass created");
                iCount = 30;
            }

            public virtual void Add() { iCount += 20; }
            public virtual void Add(int iAdd) { iCount += iAdd; }
            public void Subtract() { iCount -= 20; }
            public abstract void Subtract(int iSubtract);
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return base.ToString() + ".. Method of BaseClass";
            }
            ~CBaseClass() { Console.WriteLine("CBaseClass deleted"); }
        };

        class CDerivedClass : CBaseClass 
        {
            public CDerivedClass() 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(" CDerivedClass created.");
                iCount = 50;
            }

            public override void Add()
            {
                iCount += 20;
            }

            public void Add(int iAdd)
            { 

            iCount  += iAdd;
            }

            public void Subtract() 
            {
                iCount -= 40;
            }

            public sealed override void Subtract(int iSubtract)
            {
                iCount -= 10;
            }
            ~CDerivedClass() { Console.WriteLine("CDerivedClass deleted \n"); }

      };


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CDerivedClass deriveObject = new CDerivedClass();
            CBaseClass basePointer = new CDerivedClass();
            CDerivedClass notUsed;

            Console.WriteLine("1:" + deriveObject.iCount);
            deriveObject.Add();
            Console.WriteLine("2:" + deriveObject.iCount);
            basePointer.Add(30);
            Console.WriteLine("3:" + basePointer.iCount);
            basePointer.Subtract();
            Console.WriteLine("4:" + basePointer.iCount);
            basePointer.Subtract(20);
            Console.WriteLine("5:" + basePointer.iCount);
            Console.WriteLine("6:{0}",basePointer);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
CBaseClass created
CDerivedClass created.

CBaseClass created
CDerivedClass created.
1:50
2:70
3:80
4:60
5:50
6:TestApplication.MainClass+CDerivedClass..Method of BaseClass
```

here in above output i can't understand .. when we call base class method `add(30)`.

`basePointer.Add(30);` When we call this method... before that value of `iCount` is 70. but after this its becoming 50. how ?
i expect output of 3: 100

Comment: which values did you expect?

Comment: basePointer.Add(30); When we call this method... before that value of iCount is 70. but after this its becoming 50. how ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but `iCount` is an instance field, meaning it is not shared between `deriveObject` and `basePointer` since they are two separate objects.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25311126/497356

Comment: can you get rid of all that whitespace and other clutter like the destructors. I think you simply forgot the `override` in some of your subclass methods

Comment: then how  basePointer.iCount is 50 before this basePointer.Add(30) method

Comment: I also think it's noteworthy that your `derivedObject` and `basePointer` are the same type of object, they're both of type CDerivedClass`. So they're going to behave identically. That's fine, but I think this example is illustrating a bit of a misunderstanding of the fundamentals of polymorphism.

Comment: i expect output of 3: 100

Comment: `CBaseClass` is never instantiated in the code. Its constructor is called from a subclass.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - I see that now, the code is somewhat confusing ;)

Comment: every thing was going fine in my interview i was in 2nd last round then... they asked me o/p of this sh88t. plz help me erik and matthew

Comment: This code is way more complex than it needs to be.. For instance, Add does the same thing in base and derived.. there is no reason to override it.

Comment: I think you should review Andrew's answer below, but also just remove one of the variables all together. Run your tests with only one of them present, then run the tests with the other. That might clean up some of what's confusing you. Because it's pretty difficult for us to comprehend what you're trying for right now.

Comment: thanks matthew, eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step through the code line-by-line to see what's happening to each object's `iCount` field:

```
CDerivedClass deriveObject = new CDerivedClass();
CBaseClass basePointer = new CDerivedClass();
CDerivedClass notUsed;

// deriveObject.iCount == 50
// basePointer.iCount == 50
```

`deriveObject` and `basePointer` both have `iCount` initialized to 50 because of [the way constructors are called on derived objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882692/c-sharp-constructor-execution-order).

In this case:

- The base class constructor is called, first setting the `iCount` value to 30 and printing the base class message.
- Next, the subclass constructor is called, setting `iCount` to 50 (and overwriting the 30).

```
Console.WriteLine("1:" + deriveObject.iCount); // 1:50
deriveObject.Add();
// CDerivedClass.Add is called on deriveObject
// deriveObject.iCount == 70

Console.WriteLine("2:" + deriveObject.iCount); // 2:70
basePointer.Add(30);
// CDerivedClass.Add is called on basePointer
// basePointer.iCount == 80

Console.WriteLine("3:" + basePointer.iCount); // 3:80
basePointer.Subtract();
// CBaseClass.Subtract is called on basePointer, since `CDerivedClass` does not
// override the Subtract method.
// basePointer.iCount == 60

Console.WriteLine("4:" + basePointer.iCount); // 4:60
basePointer.Subtract(20);
// CDerivedClass.Subtract is called on basePointer. *Note* that this subtracts 10.
// basePointer.iCount == 50

Console.WriteLine("5:" + basePointer.iCount); // 5:50
Console.WriteLine("6:{0}",basePointer);

Console.ReadLine();
```

`deriveObject` and `basePointer` reference two different instances of `CDerivedClass`.

The only tricky part is with the call to `basePointer.Subtract()` ("3"). Since `CDerivedClass` does not mark its `Subtract` method as "override", the base class' method is called.

Comment: CDerivedClass deriveObject = new CDerivedClass();
CBaseClass basePointer = new CDerivedClass();
CDerivedClass notUsed;

// deriveObject.iCount == 50

Comment: up to this ok but how derived.icount get value 50 ?

Comment: Ah ok-- so you're asking about how constructors are called in this case?

Comment: ur very close to my answer

Comment: how derived.icount= 50 ?

Comment: yes you got it right...

Comment: It's 50 because you set it 50 in the constructor.  the Base class constructor is called first, setting it to 30, then the derived is called overwriting it with 50, it does this in both cases because you are instantiating a new Derived type in both cases, even though you assign it to a Base type.

Comment: The key here is that you are creating two Derived types, not a derived type and a base type.

Comment: yup 1 is abstract so direct object can't be created... thanks everyone