# how to impliment constructor in inheritence in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I am very beginner in c#. I created base class and derived class but i do not understand behavior of constructor in derived class it gives error "does not contain constructor that take 0 arguments" how to use it in derived class

```
 class A
    {
       public int x, y, z;

       public A(int i, int j)
       {
           x = i;
           y = j;
       }
        public void add(int i,int j)
        {
            z=x + y;
            Console.WriteLine(z);
        }
    }
    class B : A
    {
        public B (int k, int l)
        {
            x=k;
            y=l;
        }

        public void multi(int k,int l)
        {
            z = x * y;
            Console.WriteLine(z);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            A ad = new A(5,6);
            B m = new B(8, 9);
         }
    }
```

Comment: `B(int k,int l):base(k,l){}`

Comment: was there a question in there i missed?

Comment: maybe that question make things clearer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882692/c-sharp-constructor-execution-order

Comment: You do realize that `add` and `multi` take parameters but don't use them?

Answer (score 1):

Since B inherits A, it has to include a call to A's constructor, called the *base* contructor.

```
class B : A
{
    public B (int k, int l)
     : base(k, l)
    {
    }
}
```

This calls the code in A's constructor, populating `x` and `y` with the values in `k` and `l`.