# Why a member method of class is called before the Constructor

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

Generally, Constructor is the very first thing to be executed in class when it's instantiated.

But in following case, A member methods of the class are executed first & then the constructor.

Why is it so?

A Code Scenario :

```
namespace AbsPractice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SavingsCustomer sc = new SavingsCustomer();
            CorporateCustomer cc = new CorporateCustomer();
        }
    }

    public abstract class Customer
    {
        protected Customer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructor of Abstract Customer");
            Print();

        }

        protected abstract void Print();
    }

    public class SavingsCustomer : Customer
    {
        public SavingsCustomer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructor  of SavingsCustomer");
        }


        protected override void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Print() Method of SavingsCustomer");
        }
    }

    public class CorporateCustomer : Customer
    {
        public CorporateCustomer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructor of CorporateCustomer");
        }


        protected override void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Print() Method of CorporateCustomer");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't your console writes tell you the answer? It runs the Abstract constructor which then calls the print method... Then it runs the derived class constructor... It can hardly ignore some of the code you put in there.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882692/c-sharp-constructor-execution-order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because when you call `SavingsCustomer` ctor, first of all its base class ctor is called; in `Customer` ctor you call `Print` that's an overridden method.
So basicly before `SavingsCustomer` ctor instructions are executed, `Customer` ctor must be completely called.
Note that when you call `Print` from `Customer`, `SavingsCustomer.Print()` is executed.

This is the expected behaviour; if you want your classes to behave differently, you must change their logic. Maybe you shouldn't call an abstract method from base constructor, just to avoid what you're seeing now...

Answer (score 1):

You should never, never do this unless you have a very good reason.

Calling a virtual method from a constructor is a disaster waiting to happen.

In C# object construction follows the class hierarchy order; that is, when a constructor is invoked, the most base class constructor is called first, then the immediately derived class constructor, then the next, etc. etc. (if I'm not mistaken, in C++ it's the other way around which can lead to even more confusion).

So when you call a virtual method  from a constructor what really happens is that the virtual method, if overridden (which in your case is a guarantee), will be executed before the implementing class constructor is invoked. This means that the method could be executed before the object's state has been correctly initialized (normally via the constructor; if the method does not depend on any object state then this pattern is not an issue although I'd still not recommend it).

If it is absolutely necessary to use this pattern, good practices recommend implementing an `Initialize()` method and do any virtual calls form there. Enforcing consumers to call `Initialize` before using the object is a trivial task and you guarantee that the object's state will always be valid when the virtual call is made.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question.When You Create an object like this

```
SavingsCustomer sc = new SavingsCustomer();
```

It invokes constructor of *Customer*[base of class *SavingsCustomer*],means *Customer()*
  - which inturn invoke *Print()* from class *SavingsCustomer* as it is abstract in *Customer* Class.
 Eventhough it is a member function of *SavingsCustomer* it can be called from *Customer* class before calling constructor of *SavingsCustomer* Becuase *Print()* is declared as abstract method so **it is shared by these two  classes.**

Same happens in the following declaration

```
CorporateCustomer cc = new CorporateCustomer();
```

*Print()* from *CorporateCustomer* class is called since *SavingsCustomer.Print()* is overrided

---