# Which is valid object in C#?

Tags: c#

I have one base class **Base** and a class **Derived1** which is derived from Base class and another derived class **Derived2** which is dervied from **derived1**.

Below i have mentioned few cases of object creation ( following by Multilevel inheritance of class ). Can someone help me in understanding those cases in which object creation is not possible and why it is not possible in C# ?

```
Base b1 = new Base() //Possible 
Base b1 = new derived1() // Possible 
Derived1 d1 = new Base() // Not Possible 
Derived1 d1 = new Derived1() // Possible 
Derived2 d2 = new Derived1() // ---- 
Derived1 d1 = new Derived2() // ---- 
Derived2 d2 = new Derived2() // Possible
Derived2 d2 = new Base() // ---- 
Base b1 = new Derived2() // ----
```

Comment: This is referred to as [Liskov's Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a super easy way:

```
public class A { }
public class B : A { }
public class C : B { }
```

So it's as simple as reversing the definitions:

```
A < B < C
```

(I'm using the greater than sign here, because B is everything A is and more.  C is everything B and A are... and more.)

So A can support A, B and C.
And B can support B and C.
Lastly C can only support C.

Valid:

```
A z = new A();
A y = new B();  
A x = new C();
B w = new B();
B v = new C();
C u = new C();
```

Any other combination is not supported by C# (because of [Liskov's substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

Comment: Suppose the above class structure is created. In that case which class constructor will be called and why ? (Can you please explain for all valid and Invalid cases ?)

Comment: Normally I'd say, just ask the question.  However, since that question was asked over 6 years ago, I'll just put this link here... [C# constructor execution order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882692/c-sharp-constructor-execution-order);

Comment: And [Why Do Initializers Run In The Opposite Order As Constructors? Part One](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one/);

Answer (score 1):

Derived class has all the information about the base class, as inheritance is a "is-a" relationship.

We have a base class "Base" and a derived class "Derived"

according to inheritance rule "Derived is-a Base". All the properties of Base is present in Derived.

Base b = new Derived(); //It is possible as Derived as all the information about base.

Dervied d = new Base(); //It is not possible because base don't have the information about derived.

Comment: Base b = new Derived(); // in the memory of dervied class we can accommodate base.

Comment: Derived d = new Base(); // not possible because in memory of base we can't accommodate derived

Answer (score 0):

That's easy.  The reference (variable declared,  so left hand side) must be of less derived type.  The instance on the right side may be more derived.