# Use of temporary private variable in ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on doing some refactoring of functions in an existing ASP.NET MVC application, and came across the following small recursive function within a controller. I'm a little new still to C# & .NET, so please bear with me if I get some things wrong.

```
private int _bl;
[Session]
public void TotalMaterialSubCategories(IEnumerable<Category> materialMasterCats, int i)
{
    foreach (var materialMasterCat in materialMasterCats)
    {
        _bl = _bl + 1;
        materialMasterCat.Level = i;
        if (materialMasterCat.ChildCategories.Count != 0)
        {
            TotalMaterialSubCategories(materialMasterCat.ChildCategories.ToList(), i + 1);
            if (materialMasterCat.Parent == 0)
            {
                materialMasterCat.SortOrder = _bl;
                _bl = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing about it that concerned me is this `private int _bl` statement. Within this class, the only references to this variable are associated with this function.

I thought the line `_b1 = _b1 + 1` might not be reliable because it's not manually initialized. Looking into it though, I believe that since it's an `int`, it cannot be null or left 'uninitialized', so it's getting a default value of 0; [corroborated by the MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table). The way the recursion looks like it bubbles up makes me think it'll be set back to 0 at the end of this function call as well. Finally, I'm pretty sure each independent web request gets a separate instance of this controller, so it seems like the way this is written, it should function as expected.

However, I just sort of wondered why this would be written like this. Is there a reason that this isn't just a local variable to the function, initialized with 0? Can you rely on local private variables across functions in controllers? Also, are any of my assumptions / determinations incorrect?

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. The value of `_b1` will be initialized to 0 in each request. As to why they did it that, only the person who authored could tell you for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The thing about it that concerned me is this private int _bl statement. Within this class, the only references to this variable are associated with this function.

Obviously we can't see all the code, but if I were to believe you that this [Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)(not variable) is only referenced by this function then I would surmise that either it's left over when other methods may have referenced it and now those methods no longer exist, used it OR it used by a method to maintain state beyond the execution of any single method (event or property).

> The way the recursion looks like it bubbles up makes me think it'll be set back to 0 at the end of this function call as well.

It's *set to zero* [before the constructor is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882692/c-sharp-constructor-execution-order).

Not necessarily.  It's **only** *set back to zero* after the method ends `if (materialMasterCat.Parent == 0)` **for each instantiation of this class**.

Because controllers aren't static classes, each class create has it's own private version of `_bl` that can only (normally) be access by the class itself ([private access modifer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers)).

> However, I just sort of wondered why this would be written like this. Is there a reason that this isn't just a local variable to the function, initialized with 0?

Because then when this code ran, all of them would have a value of 1:

```
materialMasterCat.SortOrder = _bl;
```

But what's happening is that each time the function is called, it's being incremented because it's exists in the class's scope, not the functions [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/scope-and-visibility).

[For Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tAS3Dd)

> Can you rely on local private variables across functions in MVC Controllers?

Private variables are always available until a class is disposed (generally), this time is referred to as the [Lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/lifetime) of an object.

Comment: Ah right, it somehow slipped past me that it's using that field to hold state between the recursive calls; probably because it's passing `i` but not `_bl`-- Thanks for that. 

Incidentally, is there any way to know when a controller instance will be disposed of, or if a user can expect to be interacting with the same controller instance between HTTP requests?

Comment: Controller instance is created for each http request. They won't be reused. It will be disposed once you send the response back to the client.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe that since it's an int, it cannot be null or left
>   'uninitialized', so it's getting a default value of 0; corroborated by
>   the MS Docs

Try putting the `private int _bl;` inside of a function as `int _bl;` and you will see that you get a compile error because you can't perform a `_bl = _bl + 1;` operation on uninitialized value. So, it doesn't get automatically initialized in scope of a function, but it does get automatically initialized when it's a property of a class instance.

You can read more on when a value gets assigned and when it doesn't here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables This particular case falls to:

> An instance variable of a class comes
>   into existence when a new instance of that class is created, and
>   ceases to exist when there are no references to that instance and the
>   instance's destructor (if any) has executed. The initial value of an
>   instance variable of a class is the default value (Default values) of
>   the variable's type. For the purpose of definite assignment checking,
>   an instance variable of a class is considered initially assigned.

Comment: Ah, yep, thanks for the clarification on that. Do you know of any reason why it would've been written with the private object variable, rather than declaring a variable within the function as `int _bl = 0;`? Is it somehow more usable or efficient like this?

Comment: Erik Philips has a perfect answer on that.