# How to use dependency injection for a ASP.NET Core web application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have created an ASP.NET Core web app which has two classes of interest:

```
public class DBConnect
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public DBConnect(IConfiguration config) 
    { 
        _configuration = config;
    }

    public SqlConnection createConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection("Driver=SQL Server;Server=localhost;Database=EcommerceApp;Uid={uid};Pwd={password}");
    }
}
```

and :

```
public UserDataAccess(IConfiguration config) : base(config)
{
}

public string getAllUsers()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = createConnection())
    {
       //database operations
    }
}
```

Both classes depend on any instance of them being initiated to pass in the configuration parameter.

Ny question is: isn't this an endless loop? It feels like as every class depends on the configuration to be injected and also depends on the class using them to pass in the configuration, there will be a limitless loop of dependency injection and required parameters to satisfy the injection. I realize this may be a stupid question, but please bear with me as I'm still a bit new to .NET Core and the concept of dependency injection

Comment: _"so both classes depend on any instance of them being initiated to pass in the configuration parameter"_ - No, that's not the case. `IConfiguration` is registered as its own service.

Comment: DI will help manage all the service, it will help you new the configuration and let you use it in other class. Based on the condition, it will help you dispose it to improve your server performance.

Comment: It's **dependency** (no "a" anywhere to be found) - not "dependancy"

Comment: @BrandoZhang if I were to dispose of the DI, how will I use it in my program ? Can I just declare a IConfiguration interface like so : IConfiguration config = new IConfiguration() ?
I require it as I plan on using it to access values from appsettings.json

Comment: Iconfiguration is registered at the service level by asp.net core default codes. So you just need use it inside the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> isn't this an endless loop?

There is a dependency on IConfiguration, but it's not causing a circular or endless loop in the code you provided. The classes are designed to receive IConfiguration through their constructors when they are instantiated, and the higher-level classes that use them are responsible for providing the necessary dependencies. You may also want to check this out:
[C# constructor execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882692/c-sharp-constructor-execution-order)

> It feels like as every class depends on the configuration to be
> injected and also depends on the class using them to pass in the
> configuration

This one seems more like an architectural concern than a compile-time or runtime error such as circular reference or any sort of endless loop and it's not possible to discuss it without knowing more about the code itself and the problem that's needed to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern that

> every class depends on the configuration to be injected and also depends on the class using them to pass in the configuration

Design your services or classes so that **IConfiguration** doesn't need to be injected in every class or service.

Comment: yes but how ? I tried looking at other solutions for this problem but all of them are made in a way that dependancy injection is used

Comment: retrieve all configuration settings from one class and inject that class instead