# 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, compiler-errors, objectcontext

I have inherited some code (that happens a lot!) which looks a bit like this: (namespace omitted)

```
public partial class SpatialDatabase : global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
{
    public string MY_PROCEDURE(Decimal arg1, Decimal arg2)
    {
        using (EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection(this.Connection.ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            object a = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext(new EntityConnection());

            EntityCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SpatialDatabaseContext.MY_PROCEDURE";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ARG1", arg1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ARG2", arg2);

            EntityParameter resultParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("RESULT", DbType.String, 100);
            resultParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            int c = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return (string)resultParam.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me a sqiggly blue line under my class name with the error message.

I know that this code works. This is running elsewhere on site just fine.
So why would this copy give me this error?

[Edit]

In reality, what happens is that the missing constructor is added when the EDMX file is built from the database objects. That's why it's a partial class!
We learn something new every day!

[/Edit]

Comment: You need to read this first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140490/base-constructor-in-c-sharp-which-gets-called-first

Comment: @V4Vendetta Thanks for the link - how does it relate to my situation?

Comment: It relates in that you're not defining constructors properly in your inheritance. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) doesn't have any constructor that takes 0 arguments and you haven't called any base(...) constructor with your `SpatialDatabase`  class, your code is **implicitly calling default constructor `base()`** for the base class.

Your current code is equivalent to:

```
public partial class SpatialDatabase : global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
{

       SpatialDatabase() : base() //Problem is here
       {
       }

}
```

You need to call one of the following base constructor with your class constructor

- [ObjectContext(EntityConnection)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738714.aspx)
- [ObjectContext(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739017.aspx)
- [ObjectContext(EntityConnection, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738877.aspx)
- [ObjectContext(String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156503.aspx)

Comment: So does this mean that the code as it stands will not work without modification? This comes from a third party and is allegedly 'working'.

Comment: @bukko, may be you are missing a file , which hold the remaining partial class SpatialDatabase, can't be sure though. But yes in current state it shouldn't compile

Answer (score 1):

It is a warning saying that your derived class isn't providing a constructor with parameters, which you might want to pass on to the inherited class' constructor. This might potentially cause a problem.